# rsync and sshpass with systemd

Tags: rsync, systemd

I'm trying to setup a systemd timer  on a debian server doing a rsync remote backup. I wrote a systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Backup Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshpass -p "mypassword" /usr/bin/rsync --log-file=/var/log/mybackup.log --rsync-path=/bin/rsync -avE --delete /var/www/* admin@192.168.1.3:/mybackup

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I start the service, I get the following error:

```
Aug 13 23:21:44 debian systemd[1]: Started Backup Service.
Aug 13 23:21:44 debian sshpass[12564]: Unexpected remote arg: admin@192.168.1.3:/mybackup
Aug 13 23:21:44 debian sshpass[12564]: rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
Aug 13 23:21:44 debian systemd[1]: mybackup.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 13 23:21:44 debian systemd[1]: Unit mybackup.service entered failed state.
```

Running the command line manually gives no errors. Does systemd parse the command line in a different way?

Comment: Could be the wildcard in `/var/www/*` is giving you problems. Try encasing the command inside a shell, something like `ExecStart=/bin/sh "command"`

Comment: Well, the complete syntax is `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/sshpass -p …"` It works. Thank you. But the question is still: How does ExecStart handle the command string?

Answer (score 1):

> Running the command line manually gives no errors. Does systemd parse the command line in a different way?

Yes. It doesn't spawn a shell.

Furthermore, variables work differently from a shell. ${FOO} expands to a single word, while $FOO splits it on whitespace (the shell would use double quotes to define whether word splitting happens or not.)

There are also some differences on how single and double quotes work.

systemd will also expand % specifiers such as %i, %n, %h, etc.

You can find the full documentation for how systemd handles command lines here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines